# Set title to video in intent.ACTION_VIEW

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to set the title when the video is played.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

How to set title when this video is played. When I try to use the player, it takes the title from the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's impossible. You need to create your own activity with custom view and open it when you try to play some video.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that its not possible.